# What are the bricks in this picture/video?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

Can someone please identify the pieces in this picture?
I'd like to acquire these, but I'm not a LEGO enthusiast, so I don't really have an idea where to start.

[image]

For reference, the picture was taken from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TK8ABjell6A) video.

Comment: Obviously, they'll have been glued to remain in that configuration - as the cheese slopes won't have anything to hold them otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are all fairly common parts that shouldn't be hard to find. It looks like they are a [cheese slope (50746)](http://rebrickable.com/parts/50746), [a 1x1 tile (3070)](http://rebrickable.com/parts/3070a), and a [1x1 round plate (4073)](http://rebrickable.com/parts/4073).

[image: 1x1 tile][image: round 1x1 plate][image: cheese slope]

These parts are common enough that they are available in many sets, or you can purchase them separately from [LEGO Pick-a-brick](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme). If you're looking for a more affordable secondary market, you could also check out [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?q=3070a).